# Google Analytics to get employee details

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a usage metrics for my company to track the users who access certain pages. The details I'm looking for includes:

1. Employee Name
2. Employee Email
3. Department
4. Country
5. Page accessed
6. Number of times a page was viewed

I was told that Google Analytics can help in collecting information about the users who access the web pages. Is it achievable by Google Analytics to get the above information?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Google, one should not pass Personally Identifiable Information (PII) such as name and email to Google Analytics. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

Alternatively, you can generate custom GA User IDs based on the email address and perform your analysis. This link explains more:
https://reflectivedata.com/everything-need-know-google-analytics-user-id/

Answer (score 0):

The dimension you want is `ga:keyword`

You can get a full list of GA's dimensions and metrics at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets